# How to create tfs projects from a code side

Tags: tfs

I need to create a tool that can open several tfs projects and give permissions on each one to a specific group of people, I have all the group details. 
I researched on the team foundation api but didn't find a way to do what I'm looking for but rather to manage an already created project. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible from the API; however, you can create a command line script.  See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010.aspx) article.

Obviously there's nothing stopping you creating and running this script in code, as it's effectively based on an XML file.